# SQL - Delete results from SELECT query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SELECT statement for linked servers as follows;

```
SELECT [TrackingId]
FROM  [Server1\DB].[sctracking].[dbo].[scTracking] AS A
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [Server2\DB].[sctracking].[dbo]. [scTracking] AS B
WHERE A.Reserved = B.Reserved )
```

This gives me the output I am looking for, but really what I want to do is delete the results.

Can anyone advise how I would wrap a delete statement into this?

Comment: Please mark answer. It avoids people from stopping bby to answer already answered questions. Thanks

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Answer (score 1):

```
DELETE A FROM [Server1\DB].[sctracking].[dbo].[scTracking] A
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
              FROM [Server2\DB].[sctracking].[dbo]. [scTracking] AS B
WHERE A.Reserved = B.Reserved)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `DELETE` statement instead :

```
DELETE A
FROM [Server1\DB].[sctracking].[dbo].[scTracking] AS A
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 
              FROM [Server2\DB].[sctracking].[dbo].[scTracking] AS B
              WHERE A.Reserved = B.Reserved 
             );
```